# Python dictionary key change

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I am creating a sort of a database and I need to change a key in a dictionary.

```
{'lastExecution': '1-1-1970', 'wachtwoord': 'wachtwoord', 'name': {'laatsteUpdate': '1-1-1970', 'puntenAantal': '0'}}
```

How can I change the key that is now called name and still keep the data assigned to it?

PS, I am using python(3.7.0b4)

Comment: whats your output looks like and what have you tried ?

Comment: `o/p` being output

Comment: I am new to programming and I don't know what o/p means

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a try :

```
dct = {'lastExecution': '1-1-1970', 'wachtwoord': 'wachtwoord',
       'name': {'laatsteUpdate': '1-1-1970', 'puntenAantal': '0'}}

dct["new_name"] = dct.pop("name")
print(dct)
```

Output will look like :

```
{'wachtwoord': 'wachtwoord', 'new_name': {'puntenAantal': '0', 
 'laatsteUpdate': '1-1-1970'}, 'lastExecution': '1-1-1970'}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

```
D = {'lastExecution': '1-1-1970', 'wachtwoord': 'wachtwoord',
   'name': {'laatsteUpdate': '1-1-1970', 'puntenAantal': '0'}}
a = D['name'] #To save the previous value
D['new key'] = a
del D['name']
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I get this error: a = dict["name"] #To save the previous value
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: I have tried this on my Python IDE and it works fine.

Comment: @S.Benten  Dude change dict keyword to your dict name, this one also works fine.

Comment: Yeah I think he is messing that up. Anyway I edited the answer. Thanks. 
@S.Benten does it work now?

Comment: The problem is resolved thanks to your answers, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
data{'this': 'this is a message'}
data['that'] = data['this']
data.pop('this', None)
```

or in single step:

```
data[new_key] = data.pop(old_key)
```